# Mediawiki uploaded file history

Tags: php, mediawiki

I am uploading the video files in mediawiki using api. The video file is uploaded and get saved as File:Test.mp4. And that file was creating as a page. now i need to get the history of the file accessed details ie. how many times this file was accessed and whom will accessed using api. Using api i need the result of the file details. Kindly suggest us any solution

Comment: See e.g. http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:DownloadCounter

Comment: But i need to get the detials using mediawiki api itself. Is there any possibilites ? And i need to details of uploaded file edit history.

Answer (score 0):

By default, MediaWiki does not track the number of times files are downloaded, so it cannot report this information either.  Generally, this information is best obtained from your web server access logs.

To collect this information in MediaWiki, you would need to route all file downloads through a wrapper script, similar to the [img_auth.php](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual%3aImg_auth.php) script included in core MediaWiki.  In this wrapper script, you could then record in the database the number of times the file has been downloaded.

Once you've done that, writing a [MediaWiki API extension](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API_extension) to report the data should not be too difficult.